# put rows of numbers into a column with shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with many lines, like

```
1 jfkdajfd   1 2 3 5
2 fkldfjld   
3 fdkfloaf   9 10
4 fldfldkf 
5 fdskf;ak   12 1 4
```

I want to get all the numbers and put them in a column in a file, like

```
 1
 2
 3
 5
 9
 10
 12
 1
 4
```

how can I achieve this?
thanks

Comment: Are the line numbers in the file?

Comment: Also asked [on Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55910/4667)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it looks like you can do this:

```
awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;++i) {print $i}}'
```

This is assuming that all the numbers you want to print occur in column 3 or after.

Comment: Otherwise, you can do  `awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;++i) if( $i ~ /[0-9]+/ ){print $i}}'`

Comment: @axiom /[0-9]+/ would match "foo3bar" etc. You need to anchor it front and back as /^[0-9]+$/.

Comment: True. Thanks a lot for pointing this out. It should be : 
`awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;++i) if( $i ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ){print $i}}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file | while read line
do
  for i in $(echo ${line})
  do
    isnumeric=$(echo ${i} | grep -q [0-9]; echo ${?})
    if [ ${isnumeric} -eq 0 ]
    then
      echo ${i} >> outfile
    fi
  done
done
```

not bulletproof and not as elegant as the previously given solutions, but it shows what is being used for determining if this is a numeric or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read num alpha rest; do 
    [[ "$rest" ]] && printf "%s\n" $rest   # <-- variable is unquoted
done < filename
```